# Trouble running command: php bin/console make:migration

Tags: php, symfony, xampp, backend

When I create a new migration using the command:

```
php bin/console make:migration
```

the terminal displays this error:

```
The table with name ".resources_user" already exists
```

When I check into Xampp MySQL admin panel my database, I didn't see any table created.

Any idea how I can solve this problem?

I've tried to clean the cache, and deleted all migrations but it doesn't work because there's no migration created.

Comment: Is there a reason for your table name starting with dot ?